# animateTransition not called on push

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have just notated that :

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)
```

Is not called id I push my `UIViewController` :

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

Otherwise if I present my `UIViewController`:

```
navigationController?.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My animation works because animateTransition is called

**EDIT:**

it is used like that:

```
let transitionManager = TransitionManager()
nextVC.transitioningDelegate = transitionManager
navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

The full animation class is that:

```
class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    private var presenting = true

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let container = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!


        let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0)
        let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container!.frame.width, 0)

        toView.transform = offScreenRight

        container!.addSubview(toView)
        container!.addSubview(fromView)


        let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {
            fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            }) { (finished) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
         }


    }

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 2
    }

    // MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol methods
     func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
         self.presenting = true
        return self
    }
     func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = false
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Configuring a custom transition to be called on a push is completely different from configuring a custom transition to be called on a present. You have not demonstrated how you have configured either of them, actually.

Comment: Hi matt, now I have demonstrated how I have configured it @matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are saying:

```
nextVC.transitioningDelegate = transitionManager
```

That is how you configure a *present* custom transition. But it is *not* how you configure a *push* custom transition.

To configure a push custom transition, give the *navigation controller* a `delegate` (not a `transitioningDelegate`) and, in the delegate, implement:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, 
    animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, 
    from fromVC: UIViewController, 
    to toVC: UIViewController) -> 
    UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
```

Comment: Why this difference?

Comment: Uh, because a navigation push and a view controller presentation are two completely different things?

Comment: To improve your answer I add this:The UINavigationController maintains a weak reference to its delegate. If there is no strong reference then the UINavigationControllerDelegate object is deallocated once the transition is complete.

Comment: With your answer, I finally realized this method is inside UINavigationControllerDelegate, not UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate. Saved my day, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation, but I do animations using CATransitions. Set the required animation in the below code (I assume you want to slide from left edge):

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 1.0;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //choose your animation
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: false)
```